# Minipage/subfigure issue - creating a set of 4x3 graphs (12 total)

Tags: graphics, minipage, plot

I am trying to fix a 4 by 3 set of graphs, with caption, on a .tex file. The result I want to achieve is the following:

[image]

(this was done in Word. Yes, that's lame, I know.)

The code for each small graph is the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I've tried a bunch of subfigure/minipage options but the result I am getting is far from ideal (below)

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};...
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage} 
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};...
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%%
```

[image]

**EDIT**

I've fixed the positioning, but not (yet) the caption. Can someone give me a hint?

```
\newpage
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.36]
    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};...
    \end{tikzpicture} \hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.36]
    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};...
    \end{tikzpicture} \hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.36]
    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};...
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.36]
    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};...
    \end{tikzpicture} \hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.36]
    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};...
    \end{tikzpicture} \hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.36]
    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};...
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.36]
    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};...
    \end{tikzpicture} \hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.36]
    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};...
    \end{tikzpicture} \hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.36]
    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};...
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.36]
    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};...
    \end{tikzpicture} \hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.36]
    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};...
    \end{tikzpicture} \hfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.36]
    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};...
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Use `minipage` like you did but add a `\hfill` between them. To start a new row just add a linebreak. You can add a caption with `captionof{figure}{your caption}` from the `caption` package or from KOMA-Script if you're using it

Comment: you don't need subfigure or minipages or anything, just put the tikzpicture one after the other and latex will arrange them into lines, just as it does any other paragraph

Comment: @faltfe you mean like this?
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.32\linewidth}
 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
 \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
 \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};...
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.32\linewidth}
 \centering
 ...
(didn't work)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle your solution doesn't scale to 1/3 of the \linewidth automatically as you mentioned

Comment: The problem is that `tikzpicture` works with actual paper dimensions (default is `cm`), so you explicitly told it to make a picture larger than `\textwidth/3`. You probably want `\resizebox`...

Comment: @bru1987 Yes, this is what I meant. The problem with this approach is that you have to take care about the size of your drawings.

Comment: @bru1987 minipage doesn't make the pictures scale either, if you just put the tikzpicture out in a line tex will break them in to lines, so as long as you generate them so three per line fit then you will get three per line. the minipage are doing nothing useful

Comment: please do not edit solutions in to the question it makes it very hard to answer. Also you have not provided an example document that makes it easy for people to see the problem or test answers.

Answer (score 1):

little late ... but it may help someone :-)

i would draw your diagrams with the `pgfplots` package. using it is simple to define size of diagrams in dependency from `\textwidth` and preserve drawn functions' domains independent from diagram size. it also enable adding diagrams titles with option `title`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}  % define page layout

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \pgfplotsset{width=0.3\linewidth,  % digrams' size
                 scale only axis,
                 axis lines = middle,
                 grid,
                 grid style = {very thin, densely dashed},
                 xmin=-4.8, xmax=4.8, xtick={-4,-3,...,4}, xticklabels={},
                 ymin=-4.8, ymax=4.8, ytick={-4,-3,...,4}, yticklabels={},
                 xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
                 xlabel style = {anchor=west,  font=\footnotesize},
                 ylabel style = {anchor=south, font=\footnotesize},
                 title style = {yshift=1mm},
                 %
                 every axis plot post/.append style={very thick, color=blue!50, smooth},
                }
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title={$y=x$}]
\addplot [domain=-4:4] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title={$y=x^2$}]
\addplot [domain=-4:4] {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title={$y=x^3$}]
\addplot [domain=-4:4] {x^3};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title={$y=x$}]
\addplot [domain=-4:4] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title={$y=x^2$}]
\addplot [domain=-4:4] {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title={$y=x^3$}]
\addplot [domain=-4:4] {x^3};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title={$y=x$}]
\addplot [domain=-4:4] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title={$y=x^2$}]
\addplot [domain=-4:4] {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title={$y=x^3$}]
\addplot [domain=-4:4] {x^3};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title={$y=x$}]
\addplot [domain=-4:4] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title={$y=x^2$}]
\addplot [domain=-4:4] {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title={$y=x^3$}]
\addplot [domain=-4:4] {x^3};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Twelve diagrams}
\label{fig:twelve}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Answer (score 0):

does it work? Just replace the example image with your tikz code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\centering
 %%%%%%%%%start of 1st row%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example.eps}
\caption{your caption}
\label{im1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}  
        \centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example.eps}
\caption{your caption}
\label{im2}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}  
        \centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example.eps}
\caption{your caption}
\label{im3}
    \end{subfigure}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%End of 1st row %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%      
    \vskip\baselineskip
    %%%%%%%%%%%%start of 2nd row%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example.eps}
\caption{your caption}
\label{im4}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}  
        \centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example.eps}
\caption{your caption}
\label{im5}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}  
         \centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example.eps}
\caption{your caption}
\label{im6}
    \end{subfigure}
%%%%%%%%%%%%% End of 2nd row %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
    \vskip\baselineskip
    %%%%%%%%%%%%start of 3rd row%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example.eps}
\caption{your caption}
\label{im7}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}  
        \centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example.eps}
\caption{your caption}
\label{im8}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}  
        \centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example.eps}
 \caption{your caption}
 \label{im9}
    \end{subfigure}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%End of 3rd row %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
    \vskip\baselineskip
    %%%%%%%%%%%%start of 4th row%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example.eps}
 \caption{your caption}
 \label{im10}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}  
        \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example.eps}
 \caption{your caption}
 \label{im11}
    \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}  
        \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example.eps}
 \caption{your caption}
 \label{im12}
    \end{subfigure}
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%End of 4th row %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
 \end{figure*}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the hint from @PhelypeOleinik that one need `resizebox` the following will do the basic grid layout.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, tikz, caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
            \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
            \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};...
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \captionof{figure}{test}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
            \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
            \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};...
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \captionof{figure}{test}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
            \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
            \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};...
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \captionof{figure}{test}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
            \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
            \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};...
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \captionof{figure}{test}
    \end{minipage}
    \dots
\end{document}
```

Each `minipage` is using 30 % of the available `linewidth`. The gap between the `minipage`s get automatically filled by `\hfill`.